# Dynamic Javascript - Is This Valid?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, strong-typing, loose-typing

can someone tell me if this is valid javascript? I know you couldnt do this sort of thing in c# but js is a much looser language..

```
var arrayToUse = "arr" + sender.value;
for (i = 0; i <= arrayToUse.length; i++) {
    // something..
}
```

specifically - the dynamic generation of the array name..

update..

so i have an array called arrMyArray which is initialised on document ready. sender.value = "MyArray" - but could be something else eg MyArray2

I want to dyanimcally iterate over the array that is indicated by the sender.value value.

Comment: what is `sender.value`? where is `"arr" + sender.value` assigned?

Comment: it is just a string of text passed from a control.

Comment: Well... `arrayToUse` will be a string and `arrayToUse.length` gives you the length of the string. `arrayToUse` will not magically be an array.

Comment: yep that makes sense. is there any way to get the array based on its string name then?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "array based on the string name" means?

Comment: where is it assigned? if it is defined and assigned in global scope, you need to use `eval()`. I would strongly recommend against it though. There is almost always a better solution to using `eval()`. Updtae your question with what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mrchief: you do not need to use eval. Just use `window['arr' + sender.value]`.

Comment: @reid: Only if it is in global/window scope. Sorry, I should have edited my comment. I meant if it is not in global scope. (although even then I have managed to workaround to not use `eval` but `eval` is straightforward)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is entirely valid.

`arrayToUse` will be a string (regardless of the value of `sender.value` — it will be converted to a string), and `i` will iterate from `0` to the string's length).

One minor note: it should be `for (**var** i = 0; …)`, otherwise `i` will be treated as a global variable, which will almost certainly end badly if you've got multiple loops running at the same time.

**Edit**: you want to get the array based on the name? In that case you've got to look it up in whatever context the array is defined.

If it's a global array, use `window`.

For example:

```
var arrayName = "arr" + sender.value;
var array = window[arrayName];
…
```

Comment: thanks David but what i wanted to do is iterate over an actual array that had the name of the string.. make sense?

Comment: While valid (it does something, and it doesn't have syntax errors), I don't think it actually does what the author intended it to do.

Answer (score 1):

To get a variable name defined by a variable, you need to use `eval`, like so:

```
var arrayToUse = eval("arr" + sender.value);
```

However, you must be very careful with this, because controlling `sender.value` would allow someone to hijack your entire application this way. You should usually try to find another solution.

If the variable is defined at the globally, you can look it up as `window["arr" + sender.value]` instead. This is still not ideal, but is less of a security risk.

Comment: I would try to avoid using `eval` at all costs

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is access a variable with the *name* "arr" + sender.value. Accessing the variable whose *contents* are "arr + sender.value doesn't do what you want -- that's just a string.

To access the variable with that name, you can look it up as a global (globals are members of the window object in the browser):

```
window["arr" + sender.value]
```

This is safer and faster than using eval() because it doesn't run code in a JavaScript execution context to evaluate the string -- it just looks up a variable in the window object with that name.